# How to build (not install) from python wheels

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel, python-packaging

I have a workflow for installing python libraries that works something like this:

1. Download source
2. Build from `setup.py`
3. Manually install build files to a network location.

I'd like to use `pip` to handle the download and dependency resolution to change my workflow to something like this:

1. Use `pip download PACKAGE` to download python wheels for PACKAGE and all its dependencies.
2. Do a build from each wheel file for PACKAGE and all the dependencies.
3. Manually install build files to a network location.

What is the best way to do step #2 in the second workflow?  I've found lots of options for *installing* from wheels, but is there a way to simply build without installing?

I basically want the same output I would get from `python setup.py build`, but using python wheels instead of the project source.